# How to reconstruct the original data matrix after applying PCA in R

Tags: r, pca

I've applied PCA on my data using the function `prcomp` in R.

This function returns the following:

1. Variation
2. Rotation Matrix
3. Standard Deviation
4. Scores (X)

My question is: How can I reconstruct the reduced version of the data after choosing, for example, two principle components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back and forth between PCA and 'normal' space is done using the rotation matrix. Just take a close look at the matrix algebra in the chapter on PCA in your favorite multivariate statistics book. To truncate (or reduce) your dataset, just limit the rotation matrix to the PC axes you want, e.g. the first two.

Comment: Not the original data. I meant a subset of the original data after choosing the first 2 PCs. How can I use the rotation matrix to get the reduced data?

Comment: Thats what I say in the last sentence of my answer, taking a subset of the rotation matrix enables you to reconstruct the reduced original data.